# Why web.xml 'context-param' cannot have character [children]?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am just curious what happen to this `web.xml` code where I have this error `cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'context-param' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.` in the Eclipse (juno version) `Markers` view.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" 
        version="2.5" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <display-name>Spring security web application (series)</display-name>

﻿  <!-- to specifically stop trouble with multiple apps on tomcat -->
﻿  <context-param>
﻿  ﻿  <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
﻿  ﻿  <param-value>customauth_root</param-value>
﻿  </context-param>

﻿  <!-- Location of the XML file that defines the root application context
﻿  ﻿  applied by ContextLoaderListener. -->
﻿  <context-param>
﻿  ﻿  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
﻿  ﻿  <param-value>
﻿      ﻿  WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
﻿      ﻿  WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
        </param-value>
﻿  </context-param>

﻿  <!-- Loads the root application context of this web app at startup. The
﻿  ﻿  application context is then available via WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext). -->
﻿  <listener>
﻿  ﻿  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
﻿  </listener>

﻿  <listener>
﻿  ﻿  <listener-class>
﻿  ﻿  ﻿  org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
﻿  </listener>

﻿  <filter>
﻿  ﻿  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
﻿  ﻿  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
﻿  </filter>

﻿  <filter-mapping>
﻿  ﻿  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
﻿  ﻿  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
﻿  </filter-mapping>

﻿  <!-- Provides core MVC application controller. See customauth-servlet.xml. -->
﻿  <servlet>
﻿  ﻿  <servlet-name>customauth</servlet-name>
﻿  ﻿  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
﻿  ﻿  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
﻿  </servlet>

﻿  <servlet-mapping>
﻿  ﻿  <servlet-name>customauth</servlet-name>
﻿  ﻿  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
﻿  </servlet-mapping>

﻿  <servlet-mapping>
﻿  ﻿  <servlet-name>customauth</servlet-name>
﻿  ﻿  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
﻿  </servlet-mapping>

﻿  <welcome-file-list>
﻿  ﻿  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
﻿  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: because the DTD doesn't allow that element to have children?

Comment: Weird, Servlet Specefication 2.5 allows param-name and param-value. Maybe it's an Eclipse issue

Comment: I wasn't sure what is the root cause of this, I just abandon the project and recreate again.

Answer (score 9):

For starters you are using illegal characters inside your XML node param-value

You are not allowed to use "/", "<" and other chars inside a node as it will break the parsing of the XML document.

You should be using CDATA or PCDATA wrappers around your value inside the XML node.

e.g.

```
    <param-value><![CDATA[
﻿      ﻿  WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
﻿      ﻿  WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml]]>
    </param-value>
```

This was what was causing your problem.

Comment: The `/` is a valid character inside an XML node.

Comment: Good answer, even though "/" was misleading (clearly enough). My Problem was @-characters in a parameter value.

Comment: thank you for the pointer. In my case, it's because of a stray character in the request. I think that this error isn't specific, anything wrong can cause it.

Answer (score 2):

Some non-visible characters are not considered XML white space, therefore the error is displayed. Display all the white space characters by configuring the Eclipse "Text Editor" preferences, then the rouge characters will stand out. You can also use this tool to validate your XML file:

```
xmllint --noout --schema http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd XML_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

You are commenting a closing tag, look again at `<filter-mapping>`:

```
 <filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>      /*</url-pattern> 
 </filter-mapping>`
```

Answer (score 0):

This error just means you have a **typo** in your xml. Try **formatting** your XML and your typo will stand out.