# Error sign in web.xml and controller

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, web.xml, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to integrate mongoDB with spring framework. But an error sign keeps showing in my `web.xml` and controller class. Please let me know how to solve this.

My `web.xml` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Spring MongoDB  MVC</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
     <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list> 
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringMongoDBMvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMongoDBMvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My controller is :

```
package com.prjelpnt.servlets;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import     org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.BasicQuery;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.prjelpnt.domain.Users;

 @Controller
public class UserController {

public Users newUser(){
    return new Users();
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/UserServlet/createUser")
public void createUser(@ModelAttribute("SpringMongoDBMvc") Users     user,ModelMap model){

}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/getUser")
public String getUser(@ModelAttribute("SpringMongoDBMvc")int id,ModelMap model){
    //model.addAttribute("user.id", id);
    ApplicationContext ctx = 
            new     AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(com.prjelpnt.dbconfig.SpringMogoDBConfig.class);
    MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations)     ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");
    BasicQuery query1 = new BasicQuery("{_id : '"+id+"' }");
    Users user = mongoOperation.findOne(query1, Users.class);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "result";
}
public List<Users> getAllUsers(){
    return null;
}
public void deleteUser(int id){
    //Some code
}
public void modifyUser(int id, String url){
    //Some code
}
public void deleteAllUsers(){
    //Some code
}
}
```

The error explanation shown is:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'welcome-file-list' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
```

Comment: your web.xml file, have you copied and pasted that in from another source? that could be the issue

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19229950/4907475)

Comment: It's working fine after I cleaned my tomcat workspace directory and the project